# How to run animation.Funcanimation in an asyncio task?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-asyncio

I'm a beginner, so please be patient and don't downgrade my question and help me ;-)
I want to start my Scatterplot -  animation.FuncAnimation in an asyncio task
I didn't knew how to directly start it via `loop.create.task` so I started a function that calls the animate-function, which draws the plot.
How to make this code easier? I need something like:
`loop.create_task(self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animate, interval=1000))`, which doesn't work obviously

My biggest problem is the freezing of the GUI after some time

THANK YOU!

```
class MainWin(tk.Tk):


    def __init__(self, loop, interv=1/120):
            
        super().__init__() 
        self.tasks = []
        self.loop = loop
        self.tasks.append(self.loop.create_task(self.subs(interv)))
        self.tasks.append(loop.create_task(self.updater(interv)))
        [...more code...]

        self.tasks.append(loop.create_task(self.animation_starter()))
                                                                        

     async def animation_starter(self,interv):
         
         self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animate, interval=1000)
         await asyncio.sleep(interv)  


     def animate(self,interval):
       [...plot Scatterplot...]


     async def updater(self, interv):
        while True:
            self.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(interv)

     async def subs(self,interv):
       while await asyncio.sleep(interv, True):
            [...do stuff...]


def main():

  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  app = MainWin(loop)
  loop.run_forever()
  loop.close()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What did you try and what were you expecting?

I want to run my animation.Funcanimation in an asyncio-task to avoid freezing of the GUI

Comment: You need to explain what FuncAnimation does.  Offhand it does not look as if it uses asyncio.  Also I do not see where you are running the tkinter event loop, which is necessary in any tk program.  There are ways to make tkinter and asyncio play together but I don't see where you are doing that.

Comment: Funcanimation is a routine from matplotlib. It allows live data plotting.